# (UWP) How do I access my code-behind file from within a DataTemplate?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

This is basically a data binding issue.

Simply put, I have a ListView who's items are generated and use a DataTemplate to present those items. Within a DataTemplate, however, the DataContext changes to the x:DataType being used, and so I have no way to access properties located in my code-behind C# file, or even properties contained in my ViewModel. Hopefully I am being clear here:

```
<ListView 
    x:Name="MyListView"
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind mainViewModel.AdvancedNoteCollection, Mode=OneWay}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="Models:Note">
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="{ When trying to bind, I am stuck within the DataContext of the Note data type! }" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>    
</ListView>
```

However, in reality, my DataTemplate is located in a external ResourceDictionary file, which makes my situation a little more challenging. The external ResourceDictionary DOES have its own code-behind file, though, which allows me to use x:Bind in addition to traditional Binding.

Comment: Here's the dilio... Although it can be achieved with semantics a DataTemplate shouldn't have any code behind and if I was to give you any advice of my own I would say never have any code behind for it.  If you need controls to operate on code then I suggest custom controls or usercontrols and using them within the DataTemplate.  The reason is a DataTemplate should technically just operate on the data it's bound to and is mostly for manipulating the UI.  In this case, if it's possible, write out the logic into a custom control and just reference it within the template.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just need to understand what you mean more clearly here, though. Are you saying that I shouldn't have a code-behind file associated with my ResourceDictionary file? I ask because I got the idea to do that from some Microsoft example code. They made it clear that it could be used.

Comment: Now within that ResourceDictionary, I just so happen to have a DataTemplate resource, in addition to several other resources. So the DataTemplate itself does not have its own code-behind file. The ResourceDictionary that holds the DataTemplate has a code-behind file.

Comment: No, I'm not saying that at all.  Code behind in a resource dictionary enables x:Bind and is for other things... DataTemplates themselves should not have code behind associated. It's semantics, you can and if you're set on it you will but that's not how its designed to be used.

Comment: This is a common problem I face, I always refer to this article https://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/ (I dont know if this works in UWP though, only have used it in WPF)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `DataContext` of the `TextBlock` in your `ListView` to the `Page` the `ListView` is located on using an `ElementName` binding (not `x:Bind`).